# How to remove banner ads once shown

Tags: codenameone

Once a banner ad has been shown following the instructions [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/adding-google-play-ads.html), is there a way to remove it?

I want to give users the option to

A) see ads

or

B) buy IAP to remove ads

The idea is to remove the banner once the IAP has been purchased, but from what I see this isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

That's a post from 2013. We no longer recommend using that capability and it doesn't support dynamic adding/removing. I would suggest using a cn1lib for ads which is far more flexible e.g. https://github.com/shannah/admobfullscreen-codenameone

Comment: So I take it banner ads are no longer supported? (Interstitial ads are full screen ads)

Comment: Nevermind, I will just modify the sources to persist a flag and enable/disable based on that